# Azure AD Web App Token Expiration Requires Page Refresh

Tags: azure, authentication, active-directory, openid, access-token

I'm currently working on a web application that authenticates users through Azure AD via OpenID Connect. When an unauthenticated user hits the application, they are redirected to the Microsoft login page where they can input their AD credentials and login to the site. This is all good and working as expected.

The issue is that Azure AD Access Tokens only last for an hour, so if a user sits on a page for over an hour and then decides to continue working on that page (like say, make ajax calls within the page), nothing happens on the users' end (the page basically becomes unresponsive to server calls). If the user manually refreshes their page then their access is refreshed and they can continue using the application as normal, but this is obviously a problem when users have to refresh their pages every hour.

I've been looking online for solutions but I can't find anything concrete; most questions dealing with the issue address Web API calls, but I haven't found any solid information on how to deal with the issue when authenticating through the back-end (i.e authenticating with Azure AD through OpenID) while attempting to make front-end (i.e ajax) calls when the AD Access Token has expired.